# Not able to setstate with respect to array of objects: React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, setstate

I am trying to map few fields in array of objects, here in this case it is fieldnames and sort order.

I am trying to achieve server side sorting functionality where in the server takes the field name and sort type whenever I click on a field. I just need to map the field names with the sort type(ASCENDING or DESCENDING) .

I have written a sample where I am maintaining a sample array of objects with type. And on click of that column need I need to decide its sorting order

Can someone help here , Just need to achieve the tagging of sort order with the field name

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wescoff-08x8x

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IState {
  sorting: any;
}
interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sorting: [{ firstName: "" }, { lastName: "" }]
    };
  }

  sortHandler = name => {
    const sorting = Object.keys(this.state.sorting).reduce((obj, key) => {
      if (key === name) {
        obj[key] = this.state.sorting[key] === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
      } else {
        obj[key] = "";
      }
      return obj;
    }, {});

    this.setState({ sorting }, () => console.log(this.state.sorting));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span onclick={this.sortHandler("firstName")}> FirstName</span>
        <span onclick={this.sortHandler("lastName")}> LastName</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Hi vjr, please try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your click-handlers get executed immediately on `render` and with the logic you have constructed this will cause the **"Maximum update depth exceeded"** error.

Pass an anonymous function that will call your `sortHandler` instead. This will make it so the `sortHandler` only gets executed when the user clicks the span:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span onclick={() => this.sortHandler("firstName")}> FirstName</span>
        <span onclick={() => this.sortHandler("lastName")}> LastName</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

See sandbox for example on how to sort by fieldnames: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-haslett-c2z3f

Comment: Thanks much.. Now the next part is tagging the field name with the sort order.. Would you help me with this?

Comment: Sure I can take a look :)

Comment: I have got a list of field names.. I need to maintain a map of sort order with respect to each field name.. Whenever I click on that field, i should get either ASCENDING or DESCENDING along with that field :)

Comment: ah i see. Can you give us the list of field-names as well? It doesn't look like the sandbox has them :). Are you actually trying to sort by first or last name? Kind of hard to tell @vjr

Comment: For now you have only two, firstName and lastName. See the sandbox.. Say may be each field should have a sort type field.. And on click of each field (here it is span) i should get either desc or asc ( basically inversion).. So that i send this field and sort type to server.. Here the focus is only getting the current sort order value and the field name

Comment: @vjr gotcha. I legit just spent the past half hour creating a prototype on how you can sort items by the field names. Try it out and let me know what you think. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-haslett-c2z3f

Comment: Can we avoid if part by giving default value "ASC" ?

Comment: @vjr hmmm but then how would you change sorting by a different field :o

Comment: Hmm that makes sense! Guess that is there a for a reason then :P ! Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IState {
  sorting: any;
}
interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sorting: [{ firstName: "" }, { lastName: "" }]
    };
  }

  sortHandler = (name => {
    const sorting = Object.keys(this.state.sorting).reduce((obj, key) => {
      if (key === name) {
        obj[key] = this.state.sorting[key] === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
      } else {
        obj[key] = "";
      }
      return obj;
    }, {});

    this.setState({ sorting }, () => console.log(this.state.sorting));
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span onclick={() => this.sortHandler("firstName")}> FirstName</span>
        <span onclick={() => this.sortHandler("lastName")}> LastName</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Few Highlighted issue on your code, please do not import the code if you're not using which can consume memory.

Arrow function dedicated to using the function on the scope. 
Please check the scope of the variable if the variable required bind with scope

```
    const sorting = Object.keys(this.state.sorting).reduce((obj, key) => {
```

Please make sure the calling function also requires the scope this to the function. I hope your problem is solved by the initial solution. its just additional notes

Comment: Thanks man! There's one more issue I'm having which I've already highlighted with respect to tagging